# Display keyboard above toolbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, iphone-softkeyboard

I have a view with a bottom toolbar and a UIWebview that is loading an HTML page with some textboxes. Is there anyway when the user clicks on a textbox, the keyboard appears above the toolbar, that way it doesn't hide its buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to change the keyboard's location, even if you could. That would be a usability disaster.

Instead, try to move the toolbar above the keyboard if you want to keep it visible.

Comment: The UIWebView keyboard shows "Previous/Next" buttons in a toolbar right above it. Is there any way I can add my own buttons there?

Comment: Well, yes and no. You can search the UIView hierarchy to find the toolbar and add your buttons, but I don't think it will fly with the App Store reviewers.

Comment: This is just a proposed solution to a bigger problem. I'm unable to resign the keyboard from my UIWebView. I was hoping I could build a toolbar with a Done button that would resign it.

Comment: the toolbar above the default UIWebView keyboard already has a "Done" button that dismisses the keyboard.

Comment: Maybe it is a limitation in the 3.2 SDK because my UIWebView does not have the Done button...

Comment: that's really interesting because mine does, and I'm using 3.2, too.